# what is garbage collected environment in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

I want to ask some question about the iPhone or objective C. What is  'garbage collected environment'? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection is a feature of the Objective-C runtime on the Mac and is not yet available on the iPhone. There, it basically means that you don't have to worry as much about memory management and handling retain / release cycles.

Comment: thank you for your reply. And in the iPhone, is it use the view controller to handle a part or all the memory management?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Mr. Witherspoon's answer, you must `alloc` (allocate) and `release` memory space for some objects in your code. To practice good memory management, anything you have an `alloc` for you must have a matching `release`. For example:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", something];
/* ... some code ... */
[string release];
```

As you can see, my string is allocated some memory space but I release it programmatically when I won't need it anymore.